# Display Y axis in Highcharts

Tags: angular, highcharts

I need to display a lot of line charts (at least 4x2 per page), so they are small, it's a summary dashboard, so each is pretty small, height 200px, width 320px.
I need to display Y axis on the right side of each chart.
For some reason Y axis is not showing up.
I tried to put min, max, visible: true, labels, stackLabels, opposite: true  on Y axis,
it is still not displayed.

Any idea what I might be missing?
Is there a min width for that?

Please help!

Using Highcharts 6.1.2 with Angular 6.1 and highcharts-angular 2.4.

TIA,
Oleg.

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue with the sample data on some online editor?

Comment: Honestly, it is not easy to do. I am trying to modify existing application (which has 100 components), so even in graph component there is over 700 lines (+100s in HTML), it shows those small graphs in Overview mode as well as large graphs in Detailed mode (which do have Y axis on the right), so I gradually copy anything related to Yaxis into small graph section, but still no cigar. Is there something hidden like min width and height required to show Y axis?  or some other property?  any suspects?

Comment: Not sure what could have an impact on it, by default the yAxis should have appeared: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic